# Choosing specific values to update by comparing a date with the current date

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g

I'm trying to compare a specific date (in this case a billing date) and compare it with the current date (SYSDATE). Any entity whose billing date exceeds the current date by 14 days gets their account status marked as inactive. Here's the code:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS;
SET ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'Inactive'
WHERE CUST_ID IN

(   SELECT CUST_ID
    FROM BILLING
    WHERE BILLING_DATE IN
         (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(BILLING_DATE) DAYS FROM BILLING) 
    > 14)

COMMIT;
```

It won't run and I'm not quite sure where the error is. I'm using Oracle 11g Express, and working through the browser, not the command line, so I can't figure out which exact line is wrong. Any advice at all would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: More Info.
Customer Table

```
CREATE TABLE    CUSTOMERS    (
CUST_ID    NUMBER(5),
FIRST_NAME    CHAR(30),
LAST_NAME    CHAR(35),
ADDRESS    CHAR(100),
POSTAL_CODE    CHAR(8),
EMAIL_ADDRESS    VARCHAR2(100),
DATE_REGISTERED    DATE,
DATE_DISCONNECTED    DATE,
REASON_DISC    VARCHAR2(250),
EMPLOYEE_ID    NUMBER(5),
SURVEY_ID    NUMBER(5),
ACCOUNT_STATUS  CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (SURVEY_ID) REFERENCES SURVEY,
FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES
```

);

sample entry

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (1,'Alan','Abdelkarim','4712 Victorian ',' H3W 2N1','Alan.Abdelkarim@hotmail.com',(to_date('02/01/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Active');
```

billing table

```
CREATE TABLE    BILLING    (
TRANSACTION_ID    NUMBER(5),
PACKAGE_ID    NUMBER(5),
CUST_ID    NUMBER(5),
BILLING_DUE    DATE,
TRANS_TIME    CHAR(5),
TRANS_DATE  Date,
PRIMARY KEY (TRANSACTION_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PACKAGE_ID) REFERENCES PACKAGES, 
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS
```

);

A sample entry

```
INSERT INTO BILLING VALUES (1,4,1,(to_date('11/15/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')),'8:00',(to_date('11/28/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')));
```

Comment: What does "won't run" mean?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?  Does the query run but fail to update some rows you expect it to?  Does it update some rows that you don't expect it to?  Give us some sample data and tell us what the expected result is.

Comment: You may find the AskTom site useful.  Here is a specific link for your problem: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file%3Fp_file%3D6551242712657900129

Comment: Sure thing @JustinCave. I added the create table and a sample entry of both customers and billing. What I mean by 'won't run' is that when I try to run the update through the Oracle SQL Command window (in the browser, not the command line), it fails to do anything and I get back the error message 'ORA-00911 - invalid character'. I just can't figure out where my syntax mistake is.

Comment: The error you're getting is the result of the semicolon after `customers`.  A semicolon terminates a statement, you don't want your `UPDATE` statement to end at `UPDATE CUSTOMERS` so you don't want a semicolon there.

Comment: @JustinCave This helped, although now I'm getting 'ORA-00923 FROM keyword is misplaced'. I've tried rearranging it no avail. From what I'm reading it looks like my whole sub query could just be a mess and I may have to throw it. edit: Nvm, just got it. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'Inactive'
WHERE CUST_ID IN
 (SELECT CUST_ID
    FROM BILLING
    WHERE (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(BILLING_DATE)) > 14
  )
;

COMMIT;
```